# I can not connect to my host with git bash

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash

I am trying to perform a Deployment with git, when I enter the command in the git bach console it gives me the following error

```
Ssh: connect to host loupper.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

To access my server I have always used port 21, I already added the 2 keys to my cpanel and I have authorized them.
Investigating found that for other hosting services the command could be

```
Ssh -p 22 root@123.456.789.123
```

In which the port, the username and the domain are specified, but in that case the console stays static and gives no response, which could be failing?

Comment: have you tried checking if you even see the host, for example, by `ping loupper.com`?

Comment: "To access my server I have always used port 21" It seems you are trying to use port 22... (21 is weird, default for ftp)

Comment: yes, How could I specify that I want to use port 21?

Comment: ssh user@host -p 21

Comment: When I specify the port, the console is locked, does not give any answer

Answer (score 0):

To connect to your server with ssh, you need to have openssh running on your server and to open the port 22 in your firewall. `Connection timed out` means that openssh is not running, or that your port is blocked.

If you are familiar with FTP (which uses the port 21) you can setup your deployment using the ftp protocol instead of ssh. It is not recommended because it is less secure, but it is possible if you didn't understand my first sentence.